# How create new container tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

i have read about this theme but not solved. Something similar to `header` and `footer` html tag with `content`. Ok it not standard html custom tag, but i want something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <content>
      This is a text
    </content>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, I have defined CSS as:

```
content {
  backuground-color: red;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

And Javascript as:

```
var customTag = document.createElement('content');
var customTag = new customTag();
document.body.appendChild(customTag);
```

But something not work. How i can fix problem? What i forget to do more?
Thanks very much.

Comment: not sure why you would want to create your own tags? there are plenty to chose from. why not just use a div with a class?

Comment: Not sure whether you need to do like this, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/ExKLVJY

Comment: out of context but backuground-color: red; should be background-color: red;

Comment: it was error of typing.

Comment: I've posted an answer.
`<content>` used to be an HTML tag (I think)...
You have a typo here: `backuground-color` => `background-color`.
As far as I know, `var customTag = new customTag();` is not used to create tags - `document.createElement` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<content>` used to be an HTML tag (I think)...
Here's a way with `<customcontent>`, instead:

```js
var cc=document.createElement("customcontent");
cc.innerText="Hello!  I'm a custom content tag!";
document.body.append(cc);
```

```css
customcontent {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```